# how to use gradient picker for fabric js?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, gradient, color-picker

I need help for using gradient picker with fabric js. I have found a gradient picker jquery pluggin which can only change css background image property with linear and radiul gradient. The jquery pluggin is here https://github.com/tantaman/jquery-gradient-picker . But how can I collect those css gradient stops and use them for fabric js gradient properties?

Here is a documentation about how to use gradient in fabric js: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/Working-with-gradients

Comment: Please show us what the gradient picker outputs at least

Comment: For linear gradient the out put is- `linear-gradient(45deg, green 0%, yellow 50%, green 100%)`

And for radial gradient the output is- `radial-gradient(blue 0%, yellow 100%)`